# Issue in the faceebook auth dialog box

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have integrated Facebook login in my website using javascript SDK.. Everything is working fine except for the auth dialog box, which is showing only once for a user.Next time when the user logs it redirects without showing the auth dialog box.I want to show the auth dialog box each time the user logs. 
This is the code I am using

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId  : 'xxxxxxxx',
        status : true, 
        cookie : true, 
        xfbml  : true, 
        oauth  : true 
        });
        if (window!=window.top) {
            FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
        };
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {                
               window.FBlogin = function(){
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {                         
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                     var query = FB.Data.query('select name,username, email, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid={0}', response.id);
                     query.wait(function(rows) {
                     //document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = '<img src="' + rows[0].pic_square + '" alt="" />';
                        var name=rows[0].name;
                        var email=rows[0].email;
                        var uid=response.id;
                        var username=rows[0].username;
                        var pic=rows[0].pic_square;                    
                     });
    });

                        } 
                        else {
                            alert("error");

                        }                       
                    }, {scope: 'email'});                                       
                };           
            }
            else {

                var authbox = document.getElementById('FBauth');
                authbox.innerHTML="";
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.setAttribute("href","javascript:void();");
                a.setAttribute("onclick","FBlogin();");              
                authbox.appendChild(a);
                window.FBlogin = function(){
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                     var query = FB.Data.query('select name,username, email, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid={0}', response.id);
                     query.wait(function(rows) {
                        var name=rows[0].name;
                        var email=rows[0].email;
                        var uid=response.id;
                        var username=rows[0].username;
                        var pic=rows[0].pic_square;                     
                     });
                  });                           
                } 

                    }, {scope: 'email'});
                };                
            }           
        });
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
         FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                     var query = FB.Data.query('select name,username,email, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid={0}', response.id);
                     query.wait(function(rows) {
                        var name=rows[0].name;
                        var uid=response.id;
                        var email=rows[0].email;
                        var username=rows[0].username;
                        var pic=rows[0].pic_square;
                        var page='';
                        $('<input />').attr({'type':'hidden', 'id':'fbname','value':email}).appendTo('#fbaccess');
                  });
               })         
         });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {            
    });
};
```

Comment: Try refactoring your code to remove duplication. Then it will be easier to read for us.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is working fine except for the auth dialog box, which is showing only once for a user.Next time when the user logs it redirects without showing the auth dialog box.

If the user is already connected to your app and has given all of the requested permissions – then this is the *intended* behavior.

Calling FB.login again in this situation will open the popup, and close it again immediately.

> I want to show the auth dialog box each time the user logs.

I can’t see the benefit of an app behaving in such a way.

Anyways, there is a parameter to explicitly request that the user re-authenticate: auth_type=reauthenticate. This will force the user to re-enter their password. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/reauthentication/#client-side for details.

But I’m not sure that this is what you actually want.

Another way could be to *delete* permissions via your app, and then have them requested again via the `scope` parameter. That should bring up the Auth dialog again. For details on that, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions